# Matlab active contour demo ,iterate towards fixed points

Tags: matlab, contour

In this implementation of active contour it will always connects the starting and end points. Is it possible to start the snake iterating without connecting the starting and endpoints. That means  ,once I specify the region and start iterating it should be like a line enclosing towards the starting and end points. (without enclosing like a circle) . Hope I clearly mentioned the problem.  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28109-snakes--active-contour-models